# How do I display a document (rtf/doc/pdf/xps) in Silverlight? I need documentation in my app

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

This is a hard question to search for as "help" and "documentation" generates a lot of false hits. I basically want to show some simple documentation or help in my Silverlight app. And I don't want to write this in XAML, obviously, so I would love to be able to add a WordPad (or similar, free and easy) document to my app that would get display with some basic formatting in Silverlight.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do they have to be embedded in your app or would launching a web server file in a new window from a hyperlink do?

Comment: It would be very nice to have it embedded but when I think about it, it would probably be ok to launch a new browser window/app. I'll try that with a wordpad document.

Answer (score 1):

Try <strike>embedding an iframe</strike> using an iframe overlay, then you can load any HTML-like content.

There is an excellent explanation of how to do this here:
http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/09/19/hosting-html-in-silverlight-not-out-of-browser.aspx

Comment: I'd rather not be writing html for this.

Comment: So use pdf? Anything that can be rendered in the host browser window can be hosted in an iframe.