# Html from Silverlight (not out of browser)

Tags: html, silverlight, out-of-browser

I am trying to open HTML file from the local URI which I use as XML Editor, to edit xml data that come from Silverlight application, then close browser window and return back edited xml data to the Silverlight application.

I tried to use `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate` but I don't quit like it.

I have tried using a method from: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/05/10/integrating-html-into-silverlight-applications.aspx

but instanly got an exception "failed to invoke ShowJobPlanIFrame"

Is there any way to handle this task? 
"Out of browser" mode doesn't fit.

Thanks.

===========================================================================

**Update:**

It worked out using **IFrame overlay**.

Button click invokes the following code in C#:

```
var scriptObject = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("ShowJobPlanIFrame");
scriptObject.InvokeSelf(url);
```

Where "**ShowJobPlanIFrame**" is as defined at:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/05/10/integrating-html-into-silverlight-applications.aspx

This allowed me to pass data into XML editor and then get it back.

An error with JavaScript function invocation I told above, was my fault in JavaScript code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked out using IFrame overlay.

Button click invokes the following code in C#:

```
var scriptObject = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("ShowJobPlanIFrame");
scriptObject.InvokeSelf(url);
```

Where "ShowJobPlanIFrame" is as defined at:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/05/10/integrating-html-into-silverlight-applications.aspx

This allowed me to pass data into XML editor and then get it back.
An error with JavaScript function invocation I told above, was my fault in JavaScript code itself.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919065/384316

> Try using an iframe overlay, then you can load any HTML-like content.
>
> There is an excellent explanation of how to do this here:
>   http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/09/19/hosting-html-in-silverlight-not-out-of-browser.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I started using IFrame overlay. It works fine for me. Also I am able to send data to xml editor and afterwards get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `NavigationFramework` of `Silverlight`? It's capability may support your needs in a more simple way than using multiple browser pages.